# Display all albums in nggallery on a page

Tags: gallery, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I'm using the popular NextGen Gallery / nggallery plugin to handle photo albums and galleries on my site.

I can arrange photos into a album and display it using a shortcode no problem, where I'm struggling is that I want to create a master "Photo Galleries" page which will show all of the photo Albums on the site.

Any advice / ideas on how to do this? The only vaguely useful suggestion I've found online thus far is to re-arrange the albums so that I have a master albums which has everything else as a sub albums. This feels very suboptimal as each gallery / albums will need to be re-arranged on upload.

I found a duplicate of this question elsewhere on the stack network - https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1858/how-to-show-all-albums-in-wordpress-nextgen-gallery but that one doesn't have an answer and hasn't been migrated to here.

Thanks
Jona

Comment: Have you tried this? http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-nextgen-gallery-display-all-albums

Comment: doesn't your shorcode contain an ID ? so why not create a custom page template and include all there? (i know this is not an answer, but cannot seem to comment)

Comment: @bboy You will be able to leave comments [when you gain some reputation on site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 4):

I have not a ready solution, but small hints.

You get all albums from nggallery with a small sql select. This get a array with all data to the album. If you have the right fields, change the `*` and use only the fields, there store your data.

```
    global $wpdb; 
    $albumlist = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->nggalbum ORDER BY id");
```

After this result you can create in a template a list with this data, like the name as example.

```
    foreach( $albumlist as $album ) {
        echo '<b>ID: ' . $album->id . ' Name: ' . $album->name . '</b><br>';
    }
```

Before you play with a sql select please play woth the global var and the functions of nextgen. The important var of ngg is `$nggdb`. About this you can use many methods to the class of ngg, lik `get_used_galleries()`.

I know about this method. Please check the example source.

```
global $nggdb;
$galleries = array();
/* find all galleries */
foreach( $nggdb->find_all_galleries() as $gallery ) {
   // check the array $gallery
   // $gallery: name, path(wp-content), title, previewpicID, author
   array_push( $galleries, $gallery->gid );
}
/* create a temporary album with all galleries */
echo nggCreateAlbum( $galleries, 'grid' );
```